# Easier way to do this in php

Tags: php

So my question is: How can i do this easier?

```
 <?php
        $b = $geld->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $koopkoe = '1000.00';
        $koopvarken = '750.00';
        $koopschaap = '500.00';
        $koopdekip = '400.00';
        if ($session->logged_in == TRUE) {
            if ($b->balance > $koopkoe ) {
                $koe  = '';
            } else {
                $koe = 'disabled';
            } 
            if ($b->balance > $koopvarken){
                $varken = '';
            } else {
                $varken = 'disabled'; 
            }
            if ($b->balance > $koopschaap){
                $schaap = '';
            } else {
                $schaap = 'disabled'; 
            }
            if ($b->balance > $koopdekip){
                $kip = '';
            } else {
                $kip = 'disabled'; 
            }   
        } else {
               $online = 'disabled';
            }

        ?>
```

I know you can do something with a "case" or something but i dont know what that is. Also if there is a way to do this easier. Can i simply add another animal (koe varken schaap kip are animals)

~Kev

Comment: You can tidy this thing up by using `ternary operator` instead of `if..else` statements

Comment: Add your values to an array and loop through them

Comment: _"case" or something but i dont know what that is_ - well... but... you should...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe cleaner :

```
$animals = array(
 'koe' => 1000,
 'varken' => 750,
 'schaap' => 500, 
  'kip' => 400,
);

foreach ($animals as $animal => $value)
{
    ${animal} = $b->balance > $value ? '' : 'disabled';
}
```

Comment: This looks cool but i the problem is. The disabled is only used when there is not enough money in `$b->balance` or the current `$session->logged-in` is false and i only see the balance :S.

Comment: @Kev30 nope, Vincent's code does exactly the same as yours

Comment: @bartek Then where is the `$session->logged_in`?

Comment: I just rewrite your if / else ... put this into your "if $session->logged ...".

Comment: sorry! sorry! sorry! wasnt awake. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentDecaux Sorry for my nooby question but i got a 4 buttons with this in it ` <?php echo $kip; ?>` each $ is different to animal so $koe $kip $varken $schaap. How do i echo the foreach result to the button?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    $b = $geld->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $arr = array(
        'koe' => '1000.00',
        'varken' => '750.00',
        'schaap' => '500.00', 
        'kip' => '400.00'
    );
    $resultantArr = array();

    if ($session->logged_in == TRUE) {
        foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
            ${$key} = ($b->balance > $val) ? '' : 'disabled';
        }
    } else {
        $online = 'disabled';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($b->balance > $koopkoe ) {
    $koe  = '';
} else {
    $koe = 'disabled';
} 
if ($b->balance > $koopvarken){
    $varken = '';
} else {
    $varken = 'disabled'; 
}
if ($b->balance > $koopschaap){
    $schaap = '';
} else {
    $schaap = 'disabled'; 
}
if ($b->balance > $koopdekip){
    $kip = '';
} else {
    $kip = 'disabled'; 
}
```

Could be written as

```
$koe = ($b->balance > $koopkoe) ? '' : 'disabled';
$varken = ($b->balance > $koopvarken) ? '' : 'disabled';  
$schaap = ($b->balance > $koopschaap) ? '' : 'disabled'; 
$kip = ($b->balance > $koopdekip) ? '' : 'disabled';
```

See [`Ternary Operators`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more info

Answer (score 3):

You could always do something like

```
...
$array = ['koe' => 1000, 'varken' => 750, 'schaap' => 500, ...];
foreach( $array as $value => $name )
{
  ${$name} = 'disabled';
  if( $b->balance > $value )
  {
    ${$name} = '';
  }
}
...
```

and then add to the animals you want.